# Devo definir tipos globais para entidades em meus projetos TypeScript?

Tags: typescript

Tenho a seguinte dúvida, nos meus projetos TypeScript eu devo definir tipos globais para as entidades do meu projeto ou devo declará-las em um arquivo e importar sempre quando for usar. É uma dúvida sobre saber se é uma boa prática ou não.

Por exemplo, depois que conheci mais sobre arquivos `d.ts`, e que seus tipos poderiam ser definidos globalmente, eu fiquei com essa dúvida em relação a facilidade de declará tipos e interfaces e utilizar no projeto todo.

Se eu tenho um usuário que tenha nome e e-mail como atributo, eu posso fazer assim em um arquivo `d.ts`.

```js
declare global {
  interface User {
    name: string;
    mail: string;
  }
}
```

ou seria uma melhor prática declarar em um arquivo `.ts` e exportar?

```js
export interface User {
    name: string;
    mail: string;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sempre que possível, **escolha referências diretas e explicitas para seus tipos**. Tipos globais se encaixam no mesmo problemas de variáveis globais no código, onde você não sabe de onde vem, para onde vão e qual o valor delas.

O que quero dizer é seguir o segundo exemplo que você deu com `User` no arquivo `.ts`. Você importar diretamente o tipo para ser usado em outro lugar, deixa o código bem mais fácil de se entender e dar manutenção e principalmente, não polui o escopo global, seja em tipagem ou variáveis.

---

Veja bem, o que um programador vai pensar ao olhar isso?:

```
import { User } from '@/modules/user'

interface UserResponse extends User { ... }
```

> *hum...., temos então um tipo que tem como base o User...blz! Sempre que precisar de `User`, devemos importar explicitamente o tipo.*

Agora, e pra isso?:

```
interface UserResponse extends User { ... }
```

> *UAI!...., cadê esse maldito User?*

Provavelmente quando desenvolvedor descobri que `User` está definido no tipo global, ele vai se perguntar: *por que diabos isso foi definido no escopo global?*

Isso já aconteceu comigo em um projeto back-end e, como não tinha contato com o antigo desenvolvedor que fez isso para me explicar o porque dessa decisão, fiz toda a migração de 3 tipos globais para arquivos `.ts` e os importei explicitamente e em seguida removi toda a tipagem global, que no meu contexto, não fazia o menor sentido. Vai ver o dev que fez isso aprendeu em um curso e achou que aquilo era o jeito certo.

---

Se você tem tipos que precisam ser compartilhados entre várias áreas do projeto, como por exemplo, um repositório monolítico que tem o back, o front e o mobile, e ambos precisam trabalhar com o tipo `User`, o melhor a se fazer é criar um pasta com tipo compartilhados, algo como `shared-types`, criar um arquivo `.ts` e definir o tipo `User` lá dentro. Quem for usar, deve explicitamente importar deste arquivo e trabalhar com ele. Isso facilita muito a organização e entendimento de como os tipos estão sendo trabalhados.